# How we can turn json list into rows in postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

i have a query that returns a json list:

```
 select type.value -> 'components' as json_data
   from manifests m left join
        jsonb_array_elements(m.json_data->'type') as type on true
```

this returns the following data

```
[{"name": "xxx", "version": "1.1"}, {"name": "xxx2", "version": "1.2"}]
```

i can proceed it further if i use it as a text like:

```
 select *
   from jsonb_array_elements(
  '[{"name": "xxx", "version": "1.1"}, {"name": "xxx2", "version": "1.2"}]' )
```

gives

```
 {"name": "xxx", "version": "1.1"}
 {"name": "xxx2", "version": "1.2"}
```

but how i can reach the same using the first query? i cannot make it work using a subquery

update: my original data looks like this:

```
{
    "lastUpdated": 1569393969656,
    "type": [
        {
            "components": [
                {
                    "name": "xxx",
                    "version": "1.1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "xxx2",
                    "version": "1.2"
                }
            ],
            "description": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `jsonb_array_elements()` function twice :

```
select jsonb_array_elements(elm) as json_data 
  from
  (
   select jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'type') -> 'components' as elm 
     from manifests ) q
```

to be able to extract the related array elements in the subquery.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a1dfc6315a46dd5d218af815f3abbd3e)</kbd>

Comment: Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object

Comment: my original table does not hold data like that, that is already a result of a transformation (see first query)

Comment: i need a solution which uses the first query

Comment: @clairvoyant can you share the original content of `json_data` directly?

Comment: i changed parcel to type to avoid any confusion for others